# How to keep logos and text inbeetwen in a line?

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, beamerposter, logos

I am creating my first poster in LateX. I am using the [Gemini](https://github.com/anishathalye/gemini) beamer theme (TY authors btw!) and wanted to add two logos - one to the right and other to the left, approximately to the middle of header. I have found some answers about including it into \title or \authors and decided to do so.

However, after using includegraphics, it creates kind of a "stairs", where first logo is the uppermost, text inbetween is shifted a bit down and the second logo is the bottommost.

[image: You can see it here] I would like to have the logos horizontally where they are and vertically centered.

I tried raisebox and probably could hit the right numbers to make it fit, but isn't there any other automatical way to make them behave and stay in line? Or is there option to add logos without inputing them into \author / \title?
Logo tag is defined in the bottom left corner by the template it seems.

Code i added to the template to create the content:

```
\title{Placeholder}

\author{\includegraphics[width=0.2\paperwidth, left, valign= m]{logo_fei.png} Placeholder \inst{1, 2} \and Placeholder. \inst{2} \and Placeholder \inst{2} \samelineand  \includegraphics[width=0.2\paperwidth, right, valign=m]{logo_fei.png}}

\institute[shortinst]{ \inst{1} Placeholder \samelineand \inst{2} Placeholder}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable tex code you have tried so far, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Try `\smash{\includegraphics{...}}`.

Comment: @Mensch Sorry, forgot about it, edited the post. Rest is the poster.tex mentioned in the repo I linked.